# Using Regular Expressions in R

Tags: r, regex

I was wondering if anyone has a good example of using regular expressions to parse through text in R. In the example below I would like to parse through string and grab the account number, vehicle name and maint type.

```
string[0]: 3423423 

string[1]: Nissan

string[2]: Sparkplugs

 string = "This is for Account: 3423423 his vehicle Nissan is going in for Maint: Sparkplugs"
```

Comment: String manipulation in R is very clunky. From experience, I'd recommend munging your data before bringing it into R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little clunky, but it works:

```
string = "This is for Account: 3423423 his vehicle Nissan is going in for Maint: Sparkplugs"
cuts <- c("Account: ", "vehicle ", "Maint: ")

sapply(cuts, function(x){sapply(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(string, x))[2]," "),"[",1)})

   Account:      vehicle       Maint:  
   "3423423"     "Nissan" "Sparkplugs"
```

Answer (score 2):

This will give you all matches, not just one, as well as it will allow for any pattern.

You define the starting point `item`:

```
string = "This is for Account: 3423423 his vehicle Nissan is going in 
          for Maint: Sparkplugs" 

getter <- function(item, string) {
  g <- gregexpr(paste0(item, "[^ ]+"), string)
  start <- g[[1]] + nchar(item)
  end <- g[[1]] + attr(g[[1]], "match.length") - 1
  res <- mapply(substr, string, start, end)
  names(res) <- NULL
  res
}

account <-getter("Account: ", string)
vehicle <-getter("vehicle ", string)
maint <-getter("Maint: ", string)
```

Or to make it more automatic:

```
items <- c("Account: ", "vehicle ", "Maint: ")
sapply(items, function(x) getter(x, string))
```